# How to use Nuxt together with tailwind/nested using the PostCSS configuration object syntax instead of array syntax?

Tags: configuration, nested, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, postcss

My current setup is Nuxt 2.15.7 and Tailwind 3.0.9 **without "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss"**.

I'm trying to use the tailwindcss/nesting plugin to support the deep selector '>>>' - test-wise together with the postcss-nesting, as I can't get rid of the error:

> (64:3) Nested CSS was detected, but CSS nesting has not been
> configured correctly. Please enable a CSS nesting plugin *before*
> Tailwind in your configuration. See how here:
> https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting

despite my configuration is set up correctly according to the Tailwind documentation:

```
  build: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: {
        'postcss-import': true,
        'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
        'tailwindcss': {},
        'autoprefixer': {},
      },
    },
  },
```

The only difference is, I'm using the object syntax, not the array syntax and `'postcss-import': true` (tried 'postcss-import':{} as well)

Now I thought it may be working when I use the `postcss-nesting` dependency according to their docs:

```
  build: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss/nesting')(require('postcss-nesting')),
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer')
      ]
    }
  }
```

This however leads to this error:

> `Cannot find module '0'  .... /node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js`

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/configuration/#postcss-plugins

**How can I use this expression `require('tailwindcss/nesting')(require('postcss-nesting'))` together with the PostCSS Configuration Object Syntax**